# Could this be pyroxene twinning ? (thin section)

Tags: mineralogy

I found this beautiful euhedral pyroxene crystal in thin section today. There is one thing that I can´t explain though.

[image]

In crossed polarizers, the crystal shows two different interference colors, which do not change as I rotate the table (no color shifting, no extinction).

[image]

As far as I know, this happens only in basal sections. But then why are there two different interference colors ? Could it be pyroxene twinning ?

Thanks for all your answers.

Comment: Yes, this is a textbook example of pyroxene twinning.

Comment: for what it's worth there is a slight difference in colour in plane polarized light